# error:'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server

Tags: asp.net, gridview

If i put it into form tag then it solved.but`gridview is disappeared`.now what i have to d?

```
<form runat="server" id="f1">`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True">           
        </asp:Gridview></form>
```

`

Comment: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: if you are not binding gridview it will not appear

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ` character between the form and the GridView tags and try again. ALso make sure you have data coming back.